# Python group by and keep rows with greatest absolute value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe. I would like to group by `col1` and `col4` and keep rows which have the greatest absolute value in `col5`.

However I would like the final table to also include `col2` and `col3` (but I do not want to group by these columns when identifying the row with the greatest absolute value).

I tried the following:

```
results_abs_df = results_df.loc[results_df.groupby(['col1','col4',])['col5'].agg([lambda x: max(x,key=abs)])]
```

But received error `Cannot index with multidimensional key`.

I'm not sure if there's another way (cannot be too memory intensive because the dataset is large) to achieve the end result?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with helper column filled by absolute values created in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':list('aaabbb'),
                           'col2':range(6),
                           'col4':list('cccddd'),
                           'col5':[-9,5,2,10,-6,3]})
print (results_df)
  col1  col2 col4  col5
0    a     0    c    -9
1    a     1    c     5
2    a     2    c     2
3    b     3    d    10
4    b     4    d    -6
5    b     5    d     3

results_abs_df = results_df.loc[results_df.assign(new = results_df['col5'].abs())
                           .groupby(['col1','col4'])['new'].idxmax()]

print (results_abs_df)
  col1  col2 col4  col5
0    a     0    c    -9
3    b     3    d    10
```